# Python - Iterating through a list of list with a specifically formatted output; file output

Tags: python, list, file, output

Sorry to ask such a trivial question but I can't find the answer anyway and it's my first day using Python (need it for work). Think my problem is trying to use Python like C. Anyway, here is what I have:

```
for i in data:
    for j in i:
        print("{}\t".format(j))
```

Which gives me data in the form of

```
elem[0][0]
elem[1][0]
elem[2][0]
...
elem[0][1]
elem[1][1]
...
```

i.e. all at once. What I really want to do, is access each element directly so I can output the list of lists data to a file whereby the elements are separated by tabs, not commas.

Here's my bastardised Python code for outputting the array to a file:

```
k=0
with open("Output.txt", "w") as text_file:
    for j in data:
        print("{}".format(data[k]), file=text_file)
        k += 1
```

So basically, I have a list of lists which I want to save to a file in tab delimited/separated format, but currently it comes out as comma separated. My approach would involve reiterating through the lists again, element by element, and saving the output by forcing in the the tabs.

Here's data excerpts (though changed to meaningless values)

```
data
['a', 'a', 306518, ' 1111111', 'a', '-', .... ]
['a', 'a', 306518, ' 1111111', 'a', '-', .... ]
....

text_file
a    a    306518    1111111    a    -....
a    a    306518    1111111    a    -....
....
```

Comment: Would you be able to give as an example of your input and expected output. Eg. A snippet from `data` and what you would expect to be shown in the output `text_file`

Comment: Thanks, even though it was answered without the additional information I asked for, the information being there makes it much more useful to other people looking at this question for information :)

Comment: Agree completely, I've been "saved" countless times from these little comments made years after the question was posted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if data is something like this '[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]'

```
for j in data:
    text_file.write('%s\n' % '\t'.join(str(x) for x in j))
```

Comment: Works perfectly thank you! My reputation is too low to up vote but really, thank you so much.

Comment: @Rob if it worked for you then you can and should *accept* the answer (click on that check mark you see by the answer)

Comment: @Ajean Thanks for the advice, I did it just now.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in data:
    print("\t".join(i))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for the data I read in from a file, but for some reason not once that data changed (read in a file with some data, manipulated it, now the code doesn't work). Received the error: 

TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, int found.

Comment: Sure, so do `map(str, i)` instead of just `i` to convert all items to strings.  This will still be quite concise.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
with open(somefile, 'w') as your_file:
    for values in data:
        print("\t".join(valeues), file=your_file)
```